# Electron, copy a file to the websrver folder

Tags: javascript, node.js, localhost, electron

I'm using electron's dialog to get access to a user's files, now I want to upload the selected file to the webserver. In my code I'm using `fs.copyFile` but it's showing me an error because it's adding the project path to http://localhost/upload.

I will be very glad for any kind of help. Thanks

```js
dialog.showOpenDialog(dialogOptions,function(fileNames) {
        // fileNames is an array that contains all the selected 
        if (fileNames === undefined) {
            console.log("No file selected");

        } else {
            readFile(fileNames[0]);
        }
    });

    function readFile(filepath) {
        fs.readFile(filepath, 'utf-8', (err, data) => {
            if (err) {
                alert("An error ocurred reading the file :" + err.message)
                return
            }

            fileName = pathf.basename(filepath);
            // Copy the chosen file to the application's data path
            fs.copyFile(filepath, 'http://localhost/upload/' + fileName, (err) => {
               if (err) throw err;
           });

            // handle the file content 
            event.sender.send('fileData', data)
            event.sender.send('fileDataPath', filepath)

        })
    }
```

Comment: Do you have a Webserver listening on some specific port locally and an API endpoint waiting for your upload request?

Comment: yes. like this  require('http').createServer(function (request, res) {
    request.addListener('end', function () {
        file.serve(request, res)
        res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
        res.write('<form action="fileupload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">');
        res.write('</form>');
        return res.end();
    }).resume()
}).listen(9990)

Answer (score 0):

This is achievable by sending data in the form of `multipart/form-data` from an Electron app to a web server.

You can use [Express](https://expressjs.com/) which is a minimal web framework in conjunction with [multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer) express middleware to accept file upload via `multipart/form-data`, since you cant't just copy file to the web server. On the client side(Electron) you have to use some http client library(e.g. [Axios](https://github.com/axios/axios)) to send your file data over the network to the web server.